# Sending email and Attachmement with adobe flash and action script 3.0

Tags: flash, email, file-io, air, email-attachments

i try to use some source code for sending email with adobe flash and action script 3.0 that i got from internet.. here i want to send email with an attachment..but it still using adobe air as player.. and now i want to use it flash player 10.. so i can't use flash.filesystem that provided by air library.. and know how to change it if i use flashplayer 10 as player...and how my code become??? any body could help????

```
import org.bytearray.smtp.mailer.SMTPMailer;
import org.bytearray.smtp.encoding.JPEGEncoder;
import org.bytearray.smtp.encoding.PNGEnc;
import org.bytearray.smtp.events.SMTPEvent;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.*;
```

/* For air library*/

```
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.File;




// create the socket connection to any SMTP socket
// use your ISP SMTP

var myMailer:SMTPMailer = new SMTPMailer ("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 25);
var fileRef:FileReference; 

// register events
// event dispatched when mail is successfully sent
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.MAIL_SENT, onMailSent);
// event dispatched when mail could not be sent
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.MAIL_ERROR, onMailError);
// event dispatched when SMTPMailer successfully connected to the SMTP server
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.CONNECTED, onConnected);
// event dispatched when SMTP server disconnected the client for different reasons
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.DISCONNECTED, onDisconnected);
// event dispatched when the client has authenticated successfully
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.AUTHENTICATED, onAuthSuccess);
// event dispatched when the client could not authenticate
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.BAD_SEQUENCE, onAuthFailed);

// take the snapshot
send_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick ( pEvt:MouseEvent )

{
/*How to change this attachment by using adobe flash player library code and action script 3.0, not adobe air player library ?????? */
```

/* change from here........... ..........*/

```
 var attachmentFile:File=File.documentsDirectory;
 attachmentFile = attachmentFile.resolvePath("file/Questions.xml");
 var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();*/
 var myCapStream:ByteArray = myEncoder.encode ( fileRef );
 stream.open(attachmentFile,FileMode.READ);
 stream.readBytes(myCapStream,0,stream.bytesAvailable);
 stream.close();
```

/* until here.......................... */

myMailer.authenticate("x@yahoo.com","xxxx");
     myMailer.sendAttachedMail ( "x@yahoo.com", "y@gmail.com", "test", "test body", myCapStream, );

```
}

function onAuthFailed ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void

{

 status_txt.htmlText = "Authentication Error";

}

function onAuthSuccess ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void

{

 status_txt.htmlText = "Authentication OK !";

}

function onConnected ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void 

{

 status_txt.htmlText = "Connected : \n\n" + pEvt.result.message;
 status_txt.htmlText += "Code : \n\n" + pEvt.result.code;

}

function onMailSent ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ) 

{

 // when data available, read it
 status_txt.htmlText = "Mail sent :\n\n" + pEvt.result.message;
 status_txt.htmlText += "Code : \n\n" + pEvt.result.code;

}

function onMailError ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void 

{

 status_txt.htmlText = "Notification :\n\n" + pEvt.result.message;
 status_txt.htmlText += "Code : \n\n" + pEvt.result.code;

}

function onDisconnected ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void 

{

 status_txt.htmlText = "User disconnected :\n\n" + pEvt.result.message;
 status_txt.htmlText += "Code : \n\n" + pEvt.result.code;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser flash application cannot read file from disk (silently) and use network to send email. You have to load file with [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html), get ByteArray from it (not entirely sure if that is possible, try to experiment) and feed into myCapStream.